# Creating an Ember Data Adapter to Pull from Flickr API

Tags: json, rest, ember.js, model, adapter

I'm working on building an Ember App that needs to pull in photo information using the Flickr API.  I'd like some advice on how to write an adapter to pull this information into my Ember app.  My call to the Flickr API returns a JSON of the form:

```
{
"photos": {
    "page": 1,
    "pages": 2,
    "perpage": 100,
    "total": "123",
    "photo": [
        {
            "id": "1234567890",
            "owner": "1234567@123",
            "secret": "1234567890",
            "server": "1111",
            "farm": 1,
            "title": "Some Title",
            "ispublic": 1,
            "isfriend": 0,
            "isfamily": 0
        },...
        ]
    },
 "stat": "ok"
}
```

Based on the format of this response, I've determined that I cannot use the JSONAPIAdapter and must use a RESTAdapter.  The only part of the response that I'm really interested in is the photo array.  This portion of the response also seems to be properly formatted to fit an Ember Data model because it provides an id for a primary key.  I've spent a good bit of time looking through the [docs](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/models/customizing-adapters/) to find a solution to this problem, but I am still very confused as to how these adapters and serializers work.   What steps would I need to take to customize my adapter to properly pull this data into a photo model?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: This may not be the best place for such an open-ended question - what you are looking for is a guide. Have you thoroughly read this section of the docs? https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/models/ 
You may also want to check out this article. https://emberigniter.com/fit-any-backend-into-ember-custom-adapters-serializers/. The ember slack channel is a good place if you just want to chat with experts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a great book on the subject: [Ember Data in the Wild: Getting Ember Data to Work With Your API](https://leanpub.com/emberdatainthewild), by David Tang - and there is also this excellent blog article: [Fit Any Backend Into Ember with Custom Adapters & Serializers](https://emberigniter.com/fit-any-backend-into-ember-custom-adapters-serializers/) from Ember Igniter.

`https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key={api-key}&tags=flower&per_page=3&format=json`

would bring up:

```
{
  photos: {
    page: 1,
    pages: 71281,
    perpage: 3,
    total: "213841",
    photo: [
      {
        id: "35314184896",
        owner: "33472394@N00",
        secret: "e02e15d7c3",
        server: "4198",
        farm: 5,
        title: "Bird's-foot Trefoil",
        ispublic: 1,
        isfriend: 0,
        isfamily: 0
      },
    ]
  },
  stat: "ok"
}
```

So you'll need to create a model for 'photo' + an adapter to grab the data and then in the serializer munge/reformat the data how ember-data wants it to be with `normalizeResponse()` or some combination of methods to get it into an array. Where is the URL for the photo anyway?

Check out this article from David as well: [Ember Data and Custom APIs - 5 Common Serializer Customizations](http://thejsguy.com/2016/01/23/ember-data-and-custom-apis-5-common-serializer-customizations.html)

That's a rough one. I just tried to make a twiddle but there are no adapters. Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I will look into these links.  The URL for the image does not come directly in the JSON response, however, because the format of the image URLs remains consistent, I should be able to generate them fairly easily using Handlebars and the image ID.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

The data is serialized into a photo model using normalizeResponse().  The photo model mirrors the photo field in the sample JSON posted above.

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

    // app/serializers/photo.js
    export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
      normalizeResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {
        payload = {
          photo: payload.photos.photo
        };

        return this._super(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType);
      }
    });
```

My adapter is defined as follows:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

// app/adapters/photo.js
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.people.getPublicPhotos&api_key=<YOUR_KEY_HERE>&user_id=<YOUR_USER_ID_HERE>&format=json&nojsoncallback=?',
  namespace: 'api'
});
```

Thank you to [sheriffderek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1399456/sheriffderek) for sharing the great resources above.